# VS19 + VS22 causes error - Visual Studio 2017 support for ARM64 is not installed

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, hololens

I have a local building agent for a Unity|HoloLens-Project. The whole time I had VS2019 on the agend installed and everything worked well. Today I had to install VS2022 on my agent because of a different .net 6 project (so it has nothing todo with my unity stuff!).

However, after installing VS2022, my Unity project can no longer be built with VS2019. I get the following output:

```
EXEC(0,0): Error : System.NotSupportedException: Visual Studio 2017 support for ARM64 is not installed.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(46,5): Error MSB3073: Der Befehl ""C:\agent\_work\1\b\UWP_Build\Il2CppOutputProject\\IL2CPP\build\deploy\netcoreapp3.1\il2cpp.exe" --libil2cpp-static --compile-cpp -architecture=ARM64 -configuration=Release -platform=winrt -outputpath="C:\agent\_work\1\b\UWP_Build\\build\bin\ARM64\Release\GameAssembly.dll" --data-folder="C:\agent\_work\1\b\UWP_Build\\build\bin\ARM64\Release\\" -cachedirectory="C:\agent\_work\1\b\UWP_Build\\build\obj\il2cppOutputProject\ARM64\Release\\" -generatedcppdir="C:\agent\_work\1\b\UWP_Build\Il2CppOutputProject\\Source"  --incremental-g-c-time-slice=3 --baselib-directory="C:\agent\_work\1\b\UWP_Build\Players\UAP\il2cpp\ARM64\Release" --avoid-dynamic-library-copy --profiler-report --additional-defines=WINDOWS_UWP --additional-defines=UNITY_UWP --additional-defines=UNITY_WSA_10_0 --additional-defines=UNITY_WSA --additional-defines=UNITY_WINRT --additional-defines=PLATFORM_WINRT -dotnetprofile=unityaot -verbose --relative-data-path=Data/il2cpp_data --map-file-parser="C:\agent\_work\1\b\UWP_Build\Il2CppOutputProject\\IL2CPP\MapFileParser\MapFileParser.exe"" wurde mit dem Code -1 beendet.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

The whole thing makes no sense to me. If I have only VS19 installed everything runs. When I install VS22, I get this error message. I went back to the building agent myself and manually opened the project in VS19 and tried to creat/publish an APPX. There I got the already known errors displayed and one more:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Visual Studio 2017 support for ARM64 is not installed.
MSB3073 The command ""C:\agent\_work\1\b\UWP_Build\Il2CppOutputProject\\IL2CPP\build\deploy\netcoreapp3.1\il2cpp.exe" --libil2cpp-static --compile-cpp -architecture=ARM64 -configuration=Release -platform=winrt -outputpath="C:\agent\_work\1\b\UWP_Build\\build\bin\ARM64\Release\GameAssembly.dll" --data-folder="C:\agent\_work\1\b\UWP_Build\\build\bin\ARM64\Release\\" -cachedirectory="C:\agent\_work\1\b\UWP_Build\\build\obj\il2cppOutputProject\ARM64\Release\\" -generatedcppdir="C:\agent\_work\1\b\UWP_Build\Il2CppOutputProject\\Source"  --incremental-g-c-time-slice=3 --baselib-directory="C:\agent\_work\1\b\UWP_Build\Players\UAP\il2cpp\ARM64\Release" --avoid-dynamic-library-copy --profiler-report --additional-defines=WINDOWS_UWP --additional-defines=UNITY_UWP --additional-defines=UNITY_WSA_10_0 --additional-defines=UNITY_WSA --additional-defines=UNITY_WINRT --additional-defines=PLATFORM_WINRT -dotnetprofile=unityaot -verbose --relative-data-path=Data/il2cpp_data --map-file-parser="C:\agent\_work\1\b\UWP_Build\Il2CppOutputProject\\IL2CPP\MapFileParser\MapFileParser.exe"" was terminated with the code -1.
MSB8020 The build tools for v143 (platform toolset = "v143") were not found. To build using the v143 build tools, install the v143 build tools. Alternatively, upgrade to the latest Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-clicking the solution and selecting Reassign Solution.
```

Workload in my VSInstaller for VS19:
[image]

It doesn't make sense that VS17 with ARM64 is suddenly demanded.
 And it makes no sense that suddenly the build tools for version 143 are required.
 The project is opened with VS19(=v142) and not with VS22(=v143).

Comment: Is uninstalling 2019 an option for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not at the moment. But if there is no solution for that, I will try that too.

Comment: @derHugo I removed VS19 and it runs on VS22 :) **I would still like to have a solution for my case.** I have to say, that using only VS22 brought me to another issue. I use DevOps2019 and the MSBuild-Task is not compatible with VS22, so made a workaround with a script :) That issue was the reason that I didnt want to use VS22.